# Repeat Purchase Cohort Analysis in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to write a SQL code in Snowflake for a repeat purchase cohort analysis. I got the grouping and categorization of the customers correct, but my units sold and sales don't match up with the raw data because of the way I overlaid my dataset to get the subsequent purchase dates if that makes sense. What do I need to do to get the correct units and sales?

Raw Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lCiCxXsPvvPUGClan_ksID9zGWagEo8DP5N7_xbnlJQ/edit?usp=sharing

Query Result: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lFSjjkqX7ResSheo_ir-s-Jr1qHafza6tQd0uQiMaXk/edit?usp=sharing

```
SELECT "T1"."amazon-order-id"
        ,"T1"."BRAND"
        ,"T1"."buyer-email"
        ,"T2"."purchase-date" "Cohort"
        ,"T1"."purchase-date"
        ,DATEDIFF(Day, "T2"."purchase-date", "T1"."purchase-date") AS "Days Difference"
        ,CASE 
            WHEN "Days Difference" = 0
                THEN 'NTB'
            WHEN "Days Difference" < 15
                THEN '0-15 days'
            WHEN "Days Difference" < 30
                THEN '15-30 days'
            WHEN "Days Difference" < 45
                THEN '30-45 days'
            WHEN "Days Difference" < 60
                THEN '45-60 days'
            WHEN "Days Difference" < 90
                THEN '60-90 days'
            WHEN "Days Difference" > 90
                THEN '90+ days'
            END "Age"
        ,SUM("T2"."shipped-quantity") AS "Units Sold"
        ,SUM("T2"."item-price") AS "Sales"
FROM "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T1
LEFT JOIN "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T2 ON "T1"."buyer-email" = "T2"."buyer-email"
    AND "T2"."purchase-date" = (SELECT MIN("T2E"."purchase-date")
                                FROM "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T2E
                                WHERE "T1"."buyer-email" = "T2E"."buyer-email" AND "T1"."purchase-date" >= "T2E"."purchase-date")
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
    ORDER BY 2,3,4,5,
    CASE WHEN "Age" = 'NTB' THEN 1
           WHEN "Age" = '0-15 days' THEN 2
           WHEN "Age" = '15-30 days' THEN 3
           WHEN "Age" = '30-45 days' THEN 4
           WHEN "Age" = '45-60 days' THEN 5
           WHEN "Age" = '60+ days' THEN 6
           ELSE 7 END
```

Comment: Please don't tag alternative DB's when you have a specific DB you need to run the code on. And if you need to run on many, don't name any specific DB's

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you wish to find a "next date" for each order I would recommend doing it this way

```
select t1.*,
min(t2."purchase-date") as next_date
from stack t1 
left join stack t2 
on t1."buyer-email"=t2."buyer-email"
and t1."purchase-date"<t2."purchase-date"
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6;
```

regarding your query, when i add a where clause to see some results

```
where t1."buyer-email"='9zpf6sgsp2yk42g@marketplace.amazon.com'
```

this yields data which shows your metrics with respect to very first purchase for given email, which sounds like what you want?

Also consider following simple join to check if it satisfies your requirements

```
select t1.* ,
sum(t2."shipped-quantity") as no_of_prev_shipped_items,
sum(t2."item-price") as price_sum_that_doesnt_make_sense_becuase_you_need_to_weigh_it_per_item_qty
from stack t1
left join stack t2 
    on t1."buyer-email"=t2."buyer-email"               -- same emails
    and t2."purchase-date"<=t1."purchase-date"         -- for each t1 (email,date) you will have several t2(email,date) but t2 date is <= t1 date 
    where t1."buyer-email"='9zpf6sgsp2yk42g@marketplace.amazon.com'
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
order by 1,2,3,4,5,6
```